# Issue with retrieving CRM D365 Option set field Data using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, microsoft-dynamics, azure-data-factory

I have connected to my D635 instance by creating a pipeline and Dataset in azure Data Factory and have given fetchXML as source to retrieve the data. But when I preview the data I can only see number values for Option set fields in my output data.

Could anyone clarify me if we can normalize Optionset field values in ADF and use it?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading Data from Dynamics CRM to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536422/loading-data-from-dynamics-crm-to-sql-server)

Comment: Hi Arun, this is helpful.. thanks for your help on this :)                                                            But I can see some fields from my entity are missing in my output even though I have added the condition in my query. Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: pls create a new question with all the details. for now if that answer was helpful, pls upvote to help others finding it useful

Comment: @Pollyanna the missing columns are due to you not using a column map. There is an issue with D365 to ADF where it builds a dynamic map of columns based on an initial sample and because it does not return null elements you are missing the schema. See the MS documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-dynamics-crm-office-365#dynamics-as-a-source-type

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **link-entity** element in your FetchXML query. You just need to lookup the objecttypecode of your entity.

Once you have the value you can use the following to bring in the textual value of an OptionSet selection.

```
    <link-entity name="stringmap" from="attributevalue" to="____" visible="false" link-type="outer" alias="____">
        <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="objecttypecode" operator="eq" value="___"/>
        </filter>
        <attribute name="value"/>
    </link-entity>
```

**to** should be the name of the OptionSet column on the host/root entity

**alias** whatever you want to call the column in the output. I used the same value as **to**

**value** This is the object type code for your host/root entity. It is an integer value.